# Opaque type issue with nonrec syntax

Tags: ocaml

I noticed Janestreet's Core library uses a lot the following pattern:

```
module Intf = struct
  type 'a t = Value of 'a

  module type T = sig
    type nonrec 'a t = 'a t
    val some_function : unit -> int t
  end
end

module M : Intf.T = struct
  include Intf

  let some_function () = Value 42
end
```

I find it nice because it allows me to maintain my types in a single place (generally in an _intf.ml file).

My problem is that it opacify M.t, so I can't directly do the following:

```
let _ = M.Value 42
Error: Unbound constructor M.Value
```

Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

EDIT:

Here is an example looking much more like what I really have:

In m_intf.ml:

```
module Intf = struct
  type 'a t = Value of 'a

  module type M = sig
    type nonrec 'a t = 'a t
  end
end
```

in m.ml:

```
include Intf

let some_public_function () = Value 42
let some_hidden_function () = (* ... *)
```

in m.mli:

```
include M_intf.M
val some_public_function : unit -> int t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have explicitly hidden your definition of type `'a t` with `Intf.T`.

```
module M = struct
  include Intf

  let some_function () = Value 42
end
```

If you remove it, you see it is back.

Also, when you make a type abbreviation to the variant type it doesn't automatically mean, that you bring the constructors to the scope. For example,

```
module Maybe = struct
   type 'a t = Nothing | Just of 'a
end

type 'a t = 'a Maybe.t
```

Then you still need to qualify your constructors with a module name, e.g., `Maybe.Nothing`.
If you really want to bring them to your module scope, then you need:

```
type 'a t = 'a Maybe.t = Nothing | Just of 'a
```

Comment: What if I want to hide some code but still expose the type definition? I updated my question with a more precise example.

Comment: You have no other way, except explicitly specifying your definition in a signature. More precisely, if you want some one to now, that type `'a t` is actually a variant type `'a t = Value of  'a`, then it should be written in your signature. (And, it is not about `nonrec` it is about OCaml in general).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I somehow hoped that making a type t equal to another non-opaque type would make it non-opaque. ^^